# How to get Sorcerer Bloodline Arcana?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, sorcerer

I am creating a new Magus (Kapenia Dancer) and I would like to access Sorcerer Bloodline Arcana. I looked into the promising feat [Eldritch Heritage](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/eldritch-heritage/), but this one grants bloodline power only.

I know about the magus archetype [Eldritch Scion](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/Magus/archetypes/paizo-magus-archetypes/eldritch-scion), but this archetype grants Bloodrager Bloodline and not Sorcerer bloodline.

What are the way to get Sorcerer Bloodline Arcana?

If you have 3.5 or 3pp options, I will look into it. I prefer classic Paizo content though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest and only way I know is to dip. The price of your arcana is a lost of a level.

### Sorcerer

The obvious one. Take a level of Sorcerer and you gain one.

> A sorcerer must pick one bloodline upon taking her first level of sorcerer.

In fact you can even gain another one with the archetype [Crossblooded](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/Sorcerer/archetypes/paizo-sorcerer-archetypes/crossblooded):

> A crossblooded sorcerer selects two different bloodlines. The sorcerer may gain access to the skills, feats, and some of the powers of both bloodlines she is descended from [...].

### Arcanist

Vanilla Arcanist cant have a Sorcerer bloodline. They can get one with the archetype [Blood Arcanist](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/hybrid-classes/arcanist/archetypes/paizo-arcanist-archetypes/blood-arcanist/):

> A blood arcanist selects one bloodline from those available through the sorcerer bloodline class feature. The blood arcanist gains the bloodline arcana and bloodline powers of that bloodline, treating her arcanist level as her sorcerer level. The blood arcanist does not gain the class skill, bonus feats, or bonus spells from her bloodline.

Comment: I close this question for now, but I would love to get another answer.