# Can I use Bloodline Havoc on Eldritch Heritage?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, feats, sorcerer, bloodline

Sorcerer through the Orc or Draconic bloodline can add +1 per die rolled. As a [Shocking Grasp](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/s/shocking-grasp) Magus, I would love to get that. I could dip. Lets explore another (cheesy?) way.

[Eldritch Heritage](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/eldritch-heritage/) is a general feat granting a Bloodline Power, but not a Bloodline Arcana.

> Select one sorcerer bloodline. [...] You gain the first-level bloodline power for the selected bloodline. [...] You do not gain any of the other bloodline abilities.

[Bloodline Havoc](https://sites.google.com/site/pathfinderogc/classes/core-classes/sorcerer/bloodlines/bloodline-mutations/blood-havoc) is a Bloodline mutation that can replace a Bloodline power with this effect I am looking for:

> Whenever you cast a bloodrager or sorcerer spell that deals damage, add 1 point of damage per die rolled. This benefit applies only to damaging spells that belong to schools you have selected with Spell Focus or that are bloodline spells for your bloodline.
>
> This ability replaces the sorcerer's 1st-level bloodline power or the bloodrager's 4th-level bloodline power.

Of course, I got [Skill Focus](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/skill-focus-final/) for [Eldritch heritage](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/eldritch-heritage/) and [Spell Focus (evoke)](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/spell-focus-final) for
[Bloodline Havoc](https://sites.google.com/site/pathfinderogc/classes/core-classes/sorcerer/bloodlines/bloodline-mutations/blood-havoc) and all others conditions.

To use a bloodline mutation, do I need something else than a bloodline? If not, can I use Bloodline Havoc on Eldritch Heritage?

This question is related to [How to get Sorcerer Bloodline Arcana?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/121502/11129)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Blood Havoc, and other [Bloodline Mutations](https://sites.google.com/site/pathfinderogc/classes/core-classes/sorcerer/bloodlines/bloodline-mutations), are for sorcerers and bloodragers only.

> Whenever a bloodrager or a sorcerer gains a new bloodline power, she can swap her bloodline power for a bloodline mutation whose prerequisites she meets.

This won't work for a single-class magus. Eldritch Heritage does grant you a bloodline power, and it lets you have effective sorcerer levels for the purposes of using that power. But, there's nothing in Eldritch Heritage that lets a character count as a sorcerer or bloodrager for the purposes of meeting prerequisites.

As in your related question, it seems the only way to add that extra damage to Shocking Grasp is to [take a sorcerer level](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/121503/32840) and grab the Orc or Draconic bloodline. At best, you add a little bit of electricity damage to your electricity-based spells, at the cost of a spellcasting level of your primary class.

Also, even if you picked up Blood Havoc, it is ambiguous whether it will benefit your spells that scale with your magus level.

> Whenever you cast a bloodrager or sorcerer spell that deals damage

This clause can be interpreted in two ways:

1. It applies if the spell is on the sorcerer spell list. Shocking Grasp appears on both the magus and sorcerer spell lists, so you can apply Blood Havoc when you cast as a magus. If you're a Magus 5 / Sorcerer 1, that means 5d6+5 damage.
2. It only applies when you cast the spell as a sorcerer (or bloodrager). Even though Shocking Grasp appears on both lists, you can only apply Blood Havoc when you cast using your sorcerer caster level. If you're a Magus 5 / Sorcerer 1, that means only 1d6+1 damage.

The interpretation is up to the GM, because if you use both the bloodline arcana and Blood Havoc, then the magus effectively adds +2 damage *per die rolled* when casting electricity-damage spells. And since a magus can double the damage of Shocking Grasp on a critical hit... this can add up to a lot of extra damage.

A permissive GM could be persuaded to side with the first interpretation, because it is costly for a magus to gain this ability; they would need to dip at least 1 level into sorcerer, and invest two feats (Skill Focus and Eldritch Heritage).

Comment: Shocking Grasp is a bloodrager or sorcerer spell gained as Magus. The spell is on each list. I will cast it as Magus though.

Comment: While the question was not about sorcerers, there is at least one precedent on what a _<class> spell_ is with [this FAQ on the magus](http://paizo.com/paizo/faq/v5748nruor1fz#v5748eaic9rdm) which uses a similar language and supports the second interpretation.